# Should I better use varchar(6) or char(6) for an SQL Server column which values can be either 6 or 5 symbol long?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I use ISO 3166-2 codes to designate states (of many countries, not just the USA) in my database. `Code` is the primary key of my `States` table and and it is referenced by `StateCode` foreign key column of my `Cities` table.

As far as I can see, there are 5 (like `US-CA`) and 6 (like `RU-SPE`) symbol long codes in the standard.

Should I better use `varchar(6)` or `char(6)` type for the columns in SQL Server?

The database servers to be used are going to be SQL Server 2012 and Azure.

The application to access the data are based on ASP.Net 4.5 MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.

Comment: I'll vote for `VarChar`.  It avoids having any issues regarding filling the extra character, e.g. whether to use a space or null, what bit of software is responsible for filling and stripping, ... .

Comment: How about `nvarchar(6)`?

Comment: @JonathanWood - AFAIK ISO doesn't use Unicode in codes.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (the page in question is for SQL Server 2000, but should still apply):

- Use **char** when the data values in a column are expected to be consistently close to the same size.
- Use **varchar** when the data values in a column are expected to vary considerably in size.

I believe the recommendation is based on **varchar** needing extra space to store the length of the string, and (possibly) having the string stored separately from the rest of the table, resulting in slower fetches.

Hope that helps!

Comment: See [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/142692-char-vs-varchar) for a more technical description.  The responder Gang He is an SQL Server dev, and has a really nice analysis.

Answer (score 4):

`CHAR(6)` is always going to be **6 bytes** for each entry - no matter what you enter.

`VARCHAR(6)` is going to be **7 bytes** with 5 characters (5+2 overhead), **8 bytes** with 6 characters.

Any string below roughly 10 characters, I usually pick the `CHAR` type over the `VARCHAR` because the variable-length `VARCHAR` type **always** has **2 bytes overhead** for each entry.

So if you have almost exclusively 5 and 6 character strings in this situation, I would recommend using `CHAR(6)`.

I would recommend `VARCHAR` if you have longer strings, and if the variation in the length of the actual stored text inside that string is larger; e.g. I would not use `CHAR(256)` for an e-mail address - in that case, use `VARCHAR(256)` since the lengths of the e-mail addresses stored in those columns will be significant, and the 2-byte overhead for the variable length string doesn't really matter all that much compared to 256 characters in the string.